# Error: Unfortunately, App has stopped

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

I'm learning Android and followed the tutorial in Wingnity. I'm using Android Studio 2.1.3.

I have 2 java classes (MainActivity and SimpleFragmentActivity) and 3 layout (activity_main, activity_simple_fragment and fragment simple(empty)).

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. Tried to search for the solution but code seems correct.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.ramosva.sunshine;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import  java.lang.Object;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }

    public void simples(View v){

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SimpleFragmentActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
//        startService(intent);

    }

}
```

**SimpleFragmentActivity**

```
package com.example.ramosva.sunshine;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class SimpleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public SimpleFragmentActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_fragment);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{

        public PlaceholderFragment(){

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
           View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_simple_fragment, container, false);

            Button btnClickMeGym = (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.btnSimpleFragGym);
            btnClickMeGym.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked me Gym", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return rootview;
        }

    }

}
```

*Layouts*

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Simple Fragment"
        android:id="@+id/btnSimpleFragmentMain"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:onClick="simples" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_simple_fragment**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ramosva.sunshine.SimpleFragmentActivity">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />-->


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/carls" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me!"
        android:id="@+id/btnSimpleFragGym"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_simple**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone please point out the mistake here. I just followed the code that was used in Wingnity Tutorial 1: Creating Fragments.

**Error Log**

```
01-01 23:27:10.865 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ramosva.sunshine-1/lib/arm
01-01 23:27:11.005 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ramosva.sunshine-1/lib/arm
01-01 23:27:11.150 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-01 23:27:11.295 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : none
01-01 23:27:11.300 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a7cb583 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
01-01 23:27:11.300 27075-27167/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-01 23:27:11.355 27075-27167/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xae27f7c4
01-01 23:27:11.355 27075-27167/com.example.ramosva.sunshine I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-01 23:27:11.360 27075-27167/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
01-01 23:27:11.410 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
01-01 23:27:11.490 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
01-01 23:27:11.515 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@ff58432 time:10330371
01-01 23:27:13.795 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-01 23:27:13.880 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-01 23:27:14.585 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-01 23:27:14.700 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-01 23:27:14.940 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-01 23:27:15.020 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-01 23:27:15.105 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-01 23:27:15.205 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-01 23:27:15.345 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-01 23:27:15.435 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-01 23:27:15.645 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-01 23:27:15.735 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-01 23:27:16.050 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-01 23:27:16.155 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-01 23:27:16.440 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-01 23:27:16.510 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-01 23:27:16.515 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-01 23:27:16.520 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.ramosva.sunshine, PID: 27075
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method simples(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnSimpleFragmentMain'
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
01-01 23:27:18.590 27075-27075/com.example.ramosva.sunshine I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27075 SIG: 9
01-01 23:44:07.140 29325-29325/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
01-01 23:44:07.230 29325-29325/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
01-01 23:44:07.235 29325-29325/com.example.ramosva.sunshine D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-01 23:44:07.235 29325-29325/com.example.ramosva.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.ramosva.sunshine, PID: 29325
                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method simples(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnSimpleFragmentMain'
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Add the error(logcat)

Comment: What activity do you load firstly? If `MainActivity`, then how do you call `simples` in it? What is the trigger for the crash (immediately, after a click, etc.)? Finally, ALWAYS share error logs when enquiring about errors.

Comment: Added the error logs.
Apologies for that.

Comment: @Shaishav I tried to remove the parameter in method simples and called it in onCreate but it still didn't work.

Comment: Is that all of your code for `MainActivity`?

Comment: Where is your view with id `container` that should be a `Fragment` type and need to be available in `activity_simple_fragment.xml` layout file?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_fragment);
```

to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.fragment_simple);
```

You can't overrite 2 same layout in fragment and root. It should be different

Comment: Uncheck instant run and try

 

disable instant-Run:

Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run

Answer (score 0):

You tried to add a fragment to a layout  by calling `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();` in your `SimpleFragmentActivity`, but there is no layout's id is `container` in your `activity_simple_fragment.xml`. So you need to add a layout and set it's id to `container` in `activity_simple_fragment.xml`.

Comment: just tried moving the android:id="@+id/container" in activity_main.xml to activity_simple_fragment.xml and error still comes up.

Answer (score 0):

It says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method simples(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class` avoid using onClick in XML.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSimpleFragmentMain);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SimpleFragmentActivity.class););
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Here

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Simple Fragment"
    android:id="@+id/btnSimpleFragmentMain"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    //onClick removed
```